# How do I use magic sysreq keys on a Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, hotkeys

I only recently found out about the [magic system request keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). How do I use them from the keyboard on Macs with a Linux-based OS installed, or in other cases where the keyboard doesn't have a <kbd>SysReq</kbd> key? Is there a sequence that is equivalent to <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>SysReq</kbd>, or a way to create one?

Comment: Without a key generating the same scan code, which you don't have, the only option is to `echo <char> > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, where `<char>` is the key you'd press along with `M-SysRq`. (This of course assumes you're running a kernel with magic SysRq compiled into it, and have previously done `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` in `/etc/rc.local` or similar.)

Comment: @AaronMiller I meant from the keyboard, without necessarily having logged in or anything.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to find yourself a PC-style USB keyboard with a SysRq key. Linux will interpret the scan code properly no matter what architecture it's running on; the tricky part, in this case, is generating the scan code in the first place, which cannot be done from a standard Mac keyboard.

Comment: (On the other hand, it seems probable a kernel could be compiled to recognize a different scan code, such as that of the Mac's eject key, in place of SysRq; I've never felt the urge to downgrade my MBP, so wouldn't know firsthand, but I imagine someone's done it. Or perhaps you will be the first; after all, custom-hacking your kernel is half the fun of running Linux, or so I am given to understand.)

Comment: Well, that got rather long; comments converted to answer.

Answer (score 10):

Without a key generating the same scan code, which you don't have, the only option is to `echo <char> > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, where `<char>` is the key you'd press along with `M-SysRq`. (This of course assumes you're running a kernel with magic SysRq compiled into it, and have previously done `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` in `/etc/rc.local` or similar.)

If you want real magic SysRq functionality, rather than the pale imitation obtained by echoing into random /proc entries, you'll want to find yourself a PC-style USB keyboard with a SysRq key. Linux will interpret the scan code properly no matter what architecture it's running on; the tricky part, in this case, is generating the scan code in the first place, which cannot be done from a standard Mac keyboard.

(On the other hand, it seems probable a kernel could be compiled to recognize a different scan code, such as that of the Mac's eject key, in place of SysRq; I've never felt the urge to downgrade my MBP, so wouldn't know firsthand, but I imagine someone's done it. Or perhaps you will be the first; after all, custom-hacking your kernel is half the fun of running Linux, or so I am given to understand.)

*Update*: Apparently this can be done [from userspace](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mactel-support/+bug/262408/comments/17):

> Best way to go currently is to install (manually compile) the keyfuzz program and put

```
echo "786616 99" | keyfuzz -s -d /dev/input/by-id/usb-Apple_Inc._Apple_Internal_Keyboard___Trackpad-event-kbd
```

> in your /etc/profile for instance. This maps Alt-Eject on a typical Apple Macbook Pro (mine is mid-2010, 6,2), to the Alt-SysRq combination.

If you're looking for more of an old-fashioned, "Two-Fisted Tales of Linux" sort of experience, there are some kernel patches linked from that comment thread, which may offer guidance in remapping keycodes at the kernel level.

Comment: +1 for userspace _and_ kernelspace solutions. :) I would add that there's a certain program you can run (so long as it's in a `tty`) that tells you the numeric codes of each key when you press it.

Comment: It is better to put the keyfuzz command in a file that has ".sh" filename suffix in /etc/profile.d/ directory. It will be sourced by /etc/profile and is less likely to be overwritten by system updates and such.

Comment: I get error message after login after I put the command under /etc/profile.d/: "open('/dev/input/by-id/usb-Apple__Inc._Apple_Internal_Keyboard___Trackpad-event-kbd'): Permission denied"

Comment: I created a systemd .service file and installed it to run a script contaning the keyfuzz command. I just wonder, which is the best target to use for `WantedBy=` field in the .service file?`(I used multi-user.target, which seems to work fine, but I am not sure about special cases.

Comment: This [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html) seems to describe the order of targets, but maybe some target is too early for the task to succeed.

Answer (score 7):

This answer [also posted here](https://askubuntu.com/a/896806/327339).

After 3 or 4 hrs of hard searching, reading, and trial and error, **here's a more thorough and generic answer which should work for *any* Apple/Mac laptop or keyboard** In my particular case, however, I'm using this solution for a 2008 MacBook white running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Many thanks to [Bengt Olsson for his excellent instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/a/745988/327339) which gave me the necessary start to figure out the missing details.

This solution is done in the user space, and does NOT require recompiling the kernel like some suggestions.

1. Download source for keyfuzz (http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/keyfuzz/keyfuzz-0.2.tar.gz), and extract it (I can right-click it and go to "Extract Here" to extract it in my GUI file manager, for instance). To read more about keyfuzz, [see here](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/keyfuzz/). It is released under the GNU GPL 2.0 or later open source license (yaaay open source!).

   - Dont' use a directory too deep (or with spaces possibly) or else the `./configure` command below will fail.
2. Install dependencies, or else running `./configure` below may spit out some errors:

   > ```bash
   > sudo apt-get update
   > sudo apt-get install lynx xmltoman gengetopt
   > ```
3. Compile and install keyfuzz with the usual commands:

   > ```bash
   > ./configure
   > make
   > sudo make install
   > ```
4. Navigate to `/dev/input/by-id` and find your Apple keyboard that ends in "-event-kbd":

   > ```bash
   > cd /dev/input/by-id
   > ls
   > ```

   - For me it's "usb-Apple_Computer_Apple_Internal_Keyboard___Trackpad-event-kbd"
5. Add the following line to your `/etc/rc.local` file (see note below), to cause this command to run each time your computer boots up and loads this user. Notice we are using the Apple keyboard entry we just found above. This command uses keyfuzz to **map F12 or F13 on your Apple keyboard or laptop to the system "[Magic SysRq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)"**, for soft reboots.

   - To map **F12** to SysRq: `458821 99`. Many thanks to "pjjjv" for figuring that out here! https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-762665.html
   - To map **F13** to SysRq: `458856 99`.
   - Since my MacBook 2008 does not have F13, I am using the F12 option above. Also remember to use your proper keyboard entry we found above. The command I added to `rc.local` for my case is: `echo "458821 99" | keyfuzz -s -d /dev/input/by-id/usb-Apple_Computer_Apple_Internal_Keyboard___Trackpad-event-kbd`.
   - ***Note***: on recent Ubuntu versions, `/etc/rc.local` does not exist by default, but as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/919598) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53362812/4561887), it is used if it 1) exists, 2) is executable by at least the root user, and 3) contains a [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top, such as `#!/bin/sh -e`. Be sure it is owned by root and executable (`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` OR `gedit /etc/rc.local` followed by `sudo chown root:root rc.local`; then `sudo chmod u+x /etc/rc.local`).
   - Here is my entire `/etc/rc.local` file, with the appropriate entry:

   > ```bash
   > #!/bin/sh -e
   > #
   > # rc.local
   > #
   > # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
   > # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
   > # value on error.
   > #
   > # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
   > # bits.
   > #
   > # By default this script does nothing.
   >
   > echo "458821 99" | keyfuzz -s -d /dev/input/by-id/usb-Apple_Computer_Apple_Internal_Keyboard___Trackpad-event-kbd
   >
   > exit 0
   > ```
6. Reboot.

**Now I can press Alt+F12 (or you can use Alt+F13 as described above) and issue REISUB to soft-reboot your computer.** Works perfectly on my MacBook 2008 laptop running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Note that you can see the results returned by issuing REISUB as you press each key by first jumping to an alternate session with `Ctrl+Alt+F1 (F1 through F6 work actually)` before issuing the command. To get back to your main X Window session use `Ctrl+Alt+F7`.

If you get a result that says "This sysrq operation is disabled," that's normal for several of the commands, as they pose a potential security risk. The Boot one should still work, however, allowing you to soft-reboot your computer. Here is some more information on this, [from mniess here](https://askubuntu.com/a/11194/327339):

> Starting with Ubuntu 12.10 a more fine-grained control of which Magic- SysRq features are enabled is possible. Just edit the file **/etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf**.

> The file is well documented and tells you exactly how to enable which features. The current default was picked for security purposes and should only be changed if you know why you need to (for security implications see [bug #194676](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/194676)).

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. People who view your profile will see the information anyway, and the signature can be seen as spam. For more information, see the [help/behavior].

Answer (score 0):

Not magic sysreq key but if you want to reboot or poweroff when freeze state then you might can use SMC reset keys.

[Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Option] + [Power button]